# Method of Comparing Two Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am studying about classes in Python. I know that every class has its own addition method, and I would like to know how the following code works:

```
dict1 == dict2
```

If for example,

```
dict1 = {1:2} 
dict2 = {4:6,6:7}
```

So,

1.How can I present the `__eq__` method of dictionary in python ?

2.If I cant present it, how does it work?

3.What is the big-O-Notation of comparing two dictionaries? I would expect it to be the sum of number of values in each dictionary.

Comment: for cpython - you can look at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2742 - basically, the dictionaries have to be the same length and each key and value have to be identical... I'm sure this is explained nicely in a pots somewhere on SO... not having much luck finding it though... (so it's basically worse case of O(N) unless it can short circuit by a key not being present in both, or the value for a key being different between the dictionaries...)

Comment: @JonClements the comment on top explicitly says `* Gets out as soon as any difference is detected.` ;)

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah... I was just being a little more verbose :)